# Changing python version in Maya

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to update my Maya python version from 2.5 to 2.7. But I am having problems with it.

I have followed the steps in this response:

[How do I change the python version in Maya 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656593/how-do-i-change-the-python-version-in-maya-2013/14706115#14706115)

Which seems very straight forward. The problem is that it is not working for me. I follwed this set of steps precisely:

http://acaciaecho.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/choose-python-inside-maya/

I had no problem at all doing what was explaind. The issue is that when I write the below in Maya the old version of python is still being recognized:

import sys
print sys.version

The explanation does mention that they had the same issue occur but it doesn't really say how to correct it. It just says to check the paths which I did by writing this:

print sys.path

Which shows me one path being that of the old version of python (and many pointing to the new version). So I am guessing that one path needs to be changed. But how?

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The link to the site you have there walks you through it pretty well however it misses a few key steps, I think, it's been a while since I've done this. I got it working with my Maya 2013 and python 2.7, which is indeed different from Maya's, regardless..it can be simplified to just creating a PYTHONHOME variable and setting it to the version of Python you want, i.e. C:\Python27. Then set your PYTHONPATH to $PYTHONPATH;C:\Program Files\Autodesk\MayaVersion\Python\DLLs;C:\Program Files\Autodesk\MayaVersion\Python\Lib\site-packages. You have to make sure to point python to Maya Python's DLLs and of course it's site-packages so that the interpreter can run properly and pymel and maya modules can be accessed. Let me know if that helped you out! :)